# WebRTC Remote Video doesnt autoplay if unmuted with Safari in iOS 11

Tags: html, video, webrtc, ios11

As we know for an HTML5 video, "Playback will start automatically for a video element once it comes into view if both autoplay and muted are set"

Also "It's possible to unmute a video programmatically in response to a user gesture such as a click, but if you attempt to unmute a video programmatically without a user gesture, playback will pause."

Hence for a video calling app, If I want an autoplay of the remote videos, I have to keep them muted until there is a user gesture. This kills the user experience. Kindly help how to manage autoplay of remote video in unmuted state for voice. I am testing with Safari in iOS 11.2

Comment: It’s not possible.  This is here to prevent intrusive ads. If it was possible to work around, the ads would. Thus rendering the entire feature pointless. If you DO find a work around, Apple will just close that loophole next release.

Answer (score 0):

see https://webkit.org/blog/7763/a-closer-look-into-webrtc/ in the section "Media Capture and Autoplay Video" -- if you are capturing from getUserMedia you are probably good.

https://github.com/webrtc/samples/issues/929 has some notes on useful properties you might want to set.

Comment: The blog says "MediaStream-backed media will autoplay if the web page is already capturing." So, ideally Both remote and local streams should autoplay even if I keep them unmuted. However thats not the case with me. Video doesnt autoplay if I keep the Video streams unmuted and also pauses if I try to unmute them programmatically.